# How do I add a citation to a URL in lyx and zotero

Tags: latex, lyx

Hi have created a bibtek file with my citations. All is well, but now I want to cite a web page. In use the Zotero add-on of firefox. I am on the web page, and I right click on the down-arrow 2 positions right of the Z (for Zotero, on the toolbar.) Then I click "Save to Zotero using Embedded metadata". Sure enough, the web page appears in Zotero at the bottom half of the screen. Now rightclick on my collection, and export it to bibtex. I can see the .bib file in the editor, and there it is:

```
@misc{lewis_stephen_????,
title = {Stephen {Hawking}: {Artificial} {Intelligence} {Could} {End} {Human} {Race}},
shorttitle = {Stephen {Hawking}},
url = {http://www.livescience.com/48972-stephen-hawking-artificial-   intelligence-threat.html},
abstract = {Famed British physicist Stephen Hawking warned that artificial intelligence could be a threat to mankind.},
urldate = {2016-05-23},
journal = {Live Science},
author = {Lewis, Tanya and 2, Staff Writer {\textbar} December and ET, 2014 11:48am},
note = {00000},
file = {Snapshot:/home/michel/.mozilla/firefox/pongdlp4.default/zotero/storage/F72MJHIK/48972-stephen-hawking-artificial-intelligence-threat.html:text/html}
}
```

That is looking good.
Now to lyx. I do 
Add Citation. I can choose lewis_stephen_????. These 4 question marks do not look auspicious, but nevertheless, I add the citation. Then I preview my pdf, and I see the citation in the bibliography, BUT not the url.

I did put

```
\usepackage{url}
```

in the latex preamble, but this does not help. I have read this post

```
 http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35977/how-to-add-a-url-to-a-latex-bibtex-file
```

but I do not see anything that works for me. This suggestion works for me (the url in in the pdf)

```
 howpublished={\url{http://my.url.com/}}
```

But I do not want to edit the bibtek file manually, because it would get overwritten. And besides (curiously) it prints the "="  sign before the url in the output.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Michel

Comment: I found this way around the problem: In Zotero, I copy the url into the Extra field. Then all is well.